# How to change the blog title with add_filter? details below

Tags: filters, actions, blog

i want to add a prefix to all the blog title by modifying the all ready applied filter .

when i searched i got this:

```
apply_filters( 'single_post_title', string $post_title, object $post )
```

what action do i have to modify this?

```
add_filter('single_post_title', 'my_title');

function my_title() {}
```

i want this done without the javascript ..
any help is really appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the filter `single_post_title`, you can change the page/post title that is set in the `<head><title>Page title</title></head>`.

If you want to change the title that you see in the page header. ( Which i think you want to do).

Use this filter:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'modify_all_titles', 10, 2);

function modify_all_titles($title, $id) {
  return 'SOME TEXT BEFORE TITLE | '.$title;
}
```

Place this code in the functions.php (use a child theme).

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thank you :). it works ..may i ask what this filter does and how it is modified ?apply_filters( 'single_post_title', string $post_title, object $post )

Comment: Your original apply_filters code is not correct. The answer shows the correct format of the add_filter function. See the docs for how add_filter works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the wp_title function called in the title tag in the head part of the header.

```
function wpdocs_filter_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add whatever else you want
    $title .= $sep . 'whatever other information';

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpdocs_filter_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/)